# Is there a drupal 7 equivalent to the Country Ban module?

Tags: 7, advertising

I'm wondering if anyone has a Drupal specific solution for blocking entire countries from accessing your server. My company only does business in the US so there's no point in having other countries accessing my site.

For Drupal 6, there is the [Country Ban](https://drupal.org/project/countryban) module.  Is there a Drupal 7 was to do this?

Answer (score 1):

this module may help you : [Smart IP](https://drupal.org/project/smart_ip) ,,,,

> Overview Smart IP identify visitor's geographical location
>   (longitude/latitude), country, region, city and postal code based on
>   the IP address of the user. These information will be stored at
>   session variable ($_SESSION) with array key 'smart_ip' and Drupal
>   $user->data object with array key 'geoip_location' of the user but
>   optionally it can be disabled (by role) .....

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Triskelion done